# Bluetooth Audio and SoftPhone Audio Input/Output

Tags: sound, 14.04, bluetooth, hdmi, voip

I have a Voip Softphone software that I would like to start using on my Ubuntu 14.04 box.

Here's the thing.

My system sound right now goes through my HDMI to my speaker system so I can play music all day ;-)

I have a bluetooth headset connected to the machine as well.

What I am wondering is if there is a way to:

1. Auto-mute the music when a call comes in
2. Auto-switch the sound devices when a call comes in, from my hdmi sound device, to my headset
3. Auto-switch back when the call ends, and auto-un-mute the music

Or even just an auto-switch to the headset?  I can always pause the music ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wich softphone do you want to use? 
I use Yate VOIP software and on the preferences you can choose another device for ringing and answering your phone.

So your music stays on the HDMI and your call is using your headset.
You only have to mute the music by yourself.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/YateClient